# Find the Green's Function and solution of a heat equation on the half line

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the heat equation on the half line 
$$u_t = ku_{xx},\quad x > 0,\, t > 0,\\ u(x,0) = 0, \,x \in\mathbf R,\\
 u(0,t) = \alpha(t),\, t > 0.
$$
Find Green's function and the solution.

The solution is $$u(x,t) = k \cdot \int_0^t \frac{x}{\sqrt{4\pi}} \cdot \frac{ 1}{(k(t-t'))^{3/2}} \cdot  \exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{4k(t-t')}\right) \cdot \alpha(t')dt'$$

Honestly I just need guidance, I am very lost so even a similiar example would be appreciated.

Comment: It is the solution of equation $LG(x,s)=\delta(x-s)$, where $L$ is a linear differential operator and $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta function. One of the useful techniques to find such a function if the Laplace transform technique.
 

 
 

 
 

 

 $

Comment: I think it definitely helped get my head around the problem more. Our professor did give us the solution to the heat equation. I have added it to the question. Can you help tie it all in?

Comment: In fact, unless you want me to do it explicitly, the ILT of the exponential of the square root function is done here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347933/compute-the-inverse-laplace-transform-of-e-sqrtz/348021#348021 .  You then apply the convolution theorem for Laplace transforms.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know about the utility of a Green's function approach here unless you have a source term, which you don't.  I have, however, a solution based on a Laplace transform, which I will write down:

$$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{i 2 \pi} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} ds \: \hat{\alpha}(s) \exp{\left (-\sqrt{\frac{s}{k}} x \right )} \exp{(s t)}$$

where $\hat{\alpha}$ is the Laplace transform of the boundary term $\alpha(t)$:

$$\hat{\alpha}(s) = \int_0^{\infty} dt \: \alpha(t) \, \exp{(-s t)}$$

This is derived by taking a Laplace transform of the original equation:

$$\int_0^{\infty} dt \: \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} \, \exp{(-s t)} = k \int_0^{\infty} dt \: \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} \, \exp{(-s t)}$$

The LHS may be simplified by applying integration by parts:

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\infty} dt \: \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} \, \exp{(-s t)} &= \underbrace{[u(x,t) \, \exp{(-s t)}]_0^{\infty}}_{\text{this is zero}} + s \int_0^{\infty} dt \: u(x,t) \, \exp{(-s t)}\\ &= s \hat{u}(x,s)\end{align}$$

The heat equation is now

$$\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2} \hat{u}(x,s) = \frac{s}{k} \hat{u}(x,s)$$

The general solution to which is

$$\hat{u}(x,s) = A \exp{\left (\sqrt{\frac{s}{k}} x\right )} + B \exp{\left (-\sqrt{\frac{s}{k}} x\right )}$$

We now apply the boundary condition to determine $A$ and $B$.  We will have to add a condition that wasn't stated in the original posting, but is necessary for physical reasons:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} u(x,t) = 0 \: \forall t \ge 0$$

This implies that $A=0$.  We determine $B$ from the given boundary condition:

$$\hat{u}(0,s) = \hat{\alpha}(s)$$

which means that

$$\hat{u}(x,s) = \hat{\alpha}(s) \exp{\left (-\sqrt{\frac{s}{k}} x \right )}$$

We may now find the solution $u(x,t)$ from an inverse Laplace transform, which produces the result stated.

**EXAMPLE**

To illustrate how this all works, I will work a common example where $u$ represents a temperature, and the boundary condition represents the point $x=0$ being held at a fixed temperature $\alpha_0$.  Then

$$\hat{\alpha}(s)  = \alpha_0 \int_0^{\infty} dt \: \exp{(-s t)} = \frac{\alpha_0}{s}$$

The temperature for all $x$ and $t$ is then

$$u(x,t) = \frac{\alpha_0}{i 2 \pi} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} \: \frac{ds}{s} \exp{\left (-\sqrt{\frac{s}{k}} x \right )} \exp{(s t)}$$

Now, I will attack this via a contour integration, but for now, I will simply show a result from a [table of inverse Laplace transforms](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/auxiliary/inttrans/lapinv5.pdf).  The result is

$$u(x,t) = \alpha_0 \,\text{erfc}{\left (\frac{x}{2 \sqrt{k t}} \right )}$$

where erfc is the [complementary error function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/7.2).  Here is a plot of the temperature over $x$ for various values of $t$:

[image: fixed temp]

Note that the temperature is fixed at $x=0$.  Also note that,over time, the heat distributes over $x$ until, eventually, the temperature becomes uniform.

**Derivation**

Even though this ILT was found in a table, I think it is worth going through a derivation.  This result may be derived using [Cauchy's integral theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem), and requires integration in the complex plane.  If you are unfamiliar with this, then feel free to skip this derivation, as you already have a practical way of finding a solution to the heat equation as you specified.  But, again, this derivation is instructive because it gives rise to several different techniques in both complex and real integration.  A similar such complex integration can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347933/compute-the-inverse-laplace-transform-of-e-sqrtz/348021#348021).

Consider the following integral in the complex $z$ plane:

$$\oint_C \frac{dz}{z} \exp{(-\sqrt{a z})} \exp{(t z)} $$

where $a>0$ and $C$ is the following contour:

[image: contour]

We will define $\text{Arg}{z} \in (-\pi,\pi]$, so the branch is the negative real axis.  There are $6$ pieces to this contour, $C_k$, $k \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, as follows.

$C_1$ is the contour along the line $z \in [c-i R,c+i R]$ for some large value of $R$.

$C_2$ is the contour along a circular arc of radius $R$ from the top of $C_1$ to just above the negative real axis.

$C_3$ is the contour along a line just above the negative real axis between $[-R, -\epsilon]$ for some small $\epsilon$.

$C_4$ is the contour along a circular arc of radius $\epsilon$ about the origin.

$C_5$ is the contour along a line just below the negative real axis between $[-\epsilon,-R]$.

$C_6$ is the contour along the circular arc of radius $R$ from just below the negative real axis to the bottom of $C_1$.

We will show that the integral along $C_2$and $C_6$ vanish in the limits of $R \rightarrow \infty$ and $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.

On $C_2$, the real part of the argument of the exponential is

$$R t \cos{\theta} - \sqrt{a R} \cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}$$

where $\theta \in [\pi/2,\pi)$.  Clearly, $\cos{\theta} < 0$ and $\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}} > 0$, so that the integrand exponentially decays as $R \rightarrow \infty$ and therefore the integral vanishes along $C_2$.

On $C_6$, we have the same thing, but now $\theta \in (-\pi,-\pi/2]$.  This means that, due to the evenness of cosine, the integrand exponentially decays again as $R \rightarrow \infty$ and therefore the integral also vanishes along $C_6$.

Thus, we are left with the following by Cauchy's integral theorem (i.e., no poles inside $C$):

$$\left [ \int_{C_1} + \int_{C_3} + \int_{C_4} + \int_{C_5}\right] \frac{dz}{z} e^{-\sqrt{a z}} e^{z t} = 0$$

On $C_4$, note that the integral is finite and nonzero as $\epsilon$ in the limit $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$:

$$\int_{C_4} \frac{dz}{z} \exp{(-\sqrt{a z})} \exp{(t z)} \sim i \int_{\pi}^{-\pi} d\phi = -i 2 \pi $$

On $C_3$, we parametrize by $z=e^{i \pi} x$ and the integral along $C_3$ becomes

$$\int_{C_3} \frac{dz}{z} \exp{(-\sqrt{a z})} \exp{(t z)} = \int_{\infty}^0 \frac{dx}{x} \: e^{-i \sqrt{a x}} e^{-x t}$$

On $C_5$, however, we parametrize by $z=e^{-i \pi} x$ and the integral along $C_5$ becomes

$$\int_{C_5} \frac{dz}{z} \exp{(-\sqrt{a z})} \exp{(t z)} = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x} \: e^{i \sqrt{a x}} e^{-x t}$$

We may now write

$$-1 +\frac{1}{i 2 \pi} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x} \: e^{- x t} \left ( e^{i \sqrt{a x}} - e^{-i \sqrt{a x}} \right ) + \frac{1}{i 2 \pi} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} \frac{ds}{s} \: e^{-\sqrt{a s}} e^{s t} = 0$$

Therefore, the ILT of $\hat{f}(s) = \frac{e^{-\sqrt{a s}}}{s}$ is given by

$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{i 2 \pi} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} \frac{ds}{s} \: e^{-\sqrt{a s}} e^{s t}  &= 1-\frac{1}{i 2 \pi} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x} \: e^{- x t} \left ( e^{i \sqrt{a x}} - e^{-i \sqrt{a x}} \right )\\ &=1- \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} du \: \,e^{-t u^2} \frac{\sin{\sqrt{a} u}}{u} \end{align}$$

We have reduced the evaluation of the complex integral of the ILT to a single integral:

$$I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} du \: \,e^{-t u^2} \frac{\sin{\sqrt{a} u}}{u}$$

It turns out that this integral may be evaluated using an analog of [Parseval's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem) for Fourier transforms, which states that, given two functions $f$ and $g$, both $\in L^2(-\infty,\infty)$, and their Fourier transforms $F$ and $G$, respectively, the following relation holds:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \: f(x) \, g^*(x) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk \: F(k) \, G^*(k)$$

$$f(x) = e^{-t x^2} \implies F(k) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{t}} e^{-\frac{k^2}{4 t}}$$

$$g(x) = \frac{\sin{\sqrt{a} u}}{u} \implies G(k) = \begin{cases}\\ \pi & |k| < \sqrt{a}\\0 & |k| > \sqrt{a}\end{cases}$$

(These are commonly known transforms so I will not be deriving them here.  I can however point you to derivations within SE of these transforms.)

Therefore

$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} du \: \,e^{-t u^2} \frac{\sin{\sqrt{a} u}}{u} &= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{t}}  \int_{-\sqrt{a}}^{\sqrt{a}} dk \: \pi e^{-\frac{k^2}{4 t}}\\ &= \pi \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^{\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{a}{t}}} dv \: e^{-v^2} \\ &= \pi\, \text{erf}{\left ( \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{a}{t}} \right )}\end{align}$$

Now we plug this back into the expression for the ILT, with $a=x^2/k$ and get

$$\frac{\alpha_0}{i 2 \pi} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} \frac{ds}{s} \: e^{-\sqrt{a s}} e^{s t}  = \alpha_0 - \frac{\alpha_0}{\pi} \pi \, \text{erf}{\left ( \frac{x}{2 \sqrt{k t}} \right )} = \alpha_0\, \text{erfc}{\left ( \frac{x}{2 \sqrt{k t}} \right )}$$

as stated above.

**Alternative: time domain**

As expressed in the post, we can express the ILT as a convolution in the time domain.  We use the result derived [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347933/compute-the-inverse-laplace-transform-of-e-sqrtz/348021#348021)

$$\frac{1}{i 2 \pi} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} ds \: \exp{\left (-\sqrt{\frac{s}{k}} x \right )} \exp{(s t)} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{4 \pi k}} t^{-3/2} \exp{\left (-\frac{x^2}{4 k t} \right )}$$

and the convolution theorem to deduce that

$$u(x,t) = \frac{k x}{\sqrt{4 \pi}} \int_0^t dt' \: \frac{1}{[k (t-t')]^{3/2}} \exp{\left (-\frac{x^2}{4 k (t-t')} \right )} \alpha(t')$$

For $\alpha(t) = \alpha_0$, we can rewrite the integral as

$$\alpha_0 \frac{x}{\sqrt{4 \pi k}} \int_0^t dt' \: t'^{-3/2} \exp{\left (-\frac{x^2}{4 k t'} \right )}$$

By substituting $x^2/(4 k t') = u^2$, we reproduce the above result.

Comment: Thank you for the provided approach. I'm attempting to follow what you did, and from there find the solution.

Comment: This is one long answer.

Answer (score 5):

Although it's years late, I thought it might be useful for later readers to provide an answer corresponding to the original intention of the question.

For simplicity, I set $k=1$ here. Let 
$$
L=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}.
$$
It is assumed known that a *fundamental solution* (also called a *free Green's function*) is given by 
$$
E(x,t;\xi,\tau)=H(t-\tau)\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi(t-\tau)}}e^{-(x-\xi)^2/(4(t-\tau))}
$$
for $x,t,\xi,\tau\in\mathbb{R}$. Here $H$ denotes the Heaviside function. This function satisfies 
$$
LE=\delta(x-\xi)\delta(t-\tau)
$$
or 
$$
LE=\delta\bigl((x,t)-(\xi,\tau)\bigr)
$$
if you prefer. Furthermore, this fundamental solution is *causal*, which simply means that $E(x,t;\xi,\tau)=0$ whenever $t<\tau$.

The *Green's function* $g(x,t;\xi,\tau)$ for the boundary value problem satisfies the same differential equation as a fundamental solution and, in addition, satisfies the homogeneous boundary conditions, i.e., $g(x,0;\xi,\tau)=0$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $g(0,t;\xi,\tau)=0$ for $t>0$. Here we always suppose that $\xi,\tau>0$.

Using the method of images, we can construct $g$ from $E$: since $E$ is causal, the boundary condition for $t=0$ is automatically satisfied. It is then sufficient to set 
$$
g(x,t;\xi,\tau)=E(x,t;\xi,\tau)-E(x,t;-\xi,\tau)
$$
(placing a "negative image charge" at $(\xi^*,\tau^*)=(-\xi,\tau)$). It is easily checked that $g$ now satisfies the homogeneous boundary conditions. This is Green's function for the problem.

The solution of the given boundary value problem is found from 
$$
u(x,t)=\int_{\partial\varOmega} \alpha \frac{\partial g(x,t;\cdot)}{\partial n}
$$
where $\varOmega$ is the domain for the differential equation (in this case, $\{(x,t)\in\mathbb{R}^2\colon x>0,\ t>0\}$) and $\partial\varOmega$ is its boundary. The derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial n}$ denotes the *normal derivative*, i.e., the directional derivative in the direction of the (outward-pointing) normal vector to the domain $\varOmega$.

In our case, the boundary consists of the positive $x$-axis and the positive $t$-axis. Since the boundary condition on the positive $x$-axis is zero, the integral along that part will vanish, so it remains to consider the positive $t$-axis, which we parametrize by  $\gamma\colon[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}^2$, $\gamma(\tau)=(0,\tau)$.

Then the normal derivative of $g$ on the boundary is given by 
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial g(x,t;\cdot)}{\partial n}\biggr|_{\gamma(\tau)}&=-\frac{\partial}{\partial\xi}g(x,t;\xi,\tau)\biggr|_{\xi=0} \\
&=H(t-\tau)\frac{2(x-\xi)}{4(t-\tau)\sqrt{4\pi(t-\tau)}}e^{-(x-\xi)^2/(4(t-\tau))}\biggr|_{\xi=0}\\
&\quad\ -H(t-\tau)\frac{-2(x+\xi)}{4(t-\tau)\sqrt{4\pi(t-\tau)}} e^{-(x+\xi)^2/(4(t-\tau))}\biggr|_{\xi=0} \\
&=H(t-\tau)\frac{x}{\sqrt{4\pi}(t-\tau)^{3/2}}e^{-x^2/(4(t-\tau))}
\end{align*}
The line integral for the solution hence becomes
\begin{align*}
  u(x,t)&=\int_{0}^\infty \alpha(\tau) H(t-\tau)\frac{x}{\sqrt{4\pi}(t-\tau)^{3/2}}e^{-x^2/(4(t-\tau))}\, d\tau \\
  &=\frac{x}{\sqrt{4\pi}} \int_0^t\frac{\alpha(\tau)}{(t-\tau)^{3/2}}e^{-x^2/(4(t-\tau))}\, d\tau.
  \end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Let $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ ,

Then $X(x)T'(t)=kX''(x)T(t)$

$\dfrac{T'(t)}{kT(t)}=\dfrac{X''(x)}{X(x)}=-s^2$

$\begin{cases}\dfrac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=-ks^2\\X''(x)+s^2X(x)=0\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}T(t)=c_3(s)e^{-kts^2}\\X(x)=\begin{cases}c_1(s)\sin xs+c_2(s)\cos xs&\text{when}~s\neq0\\c_1x+c_2&\text{when}~s=0\end{cases}\end{cases}$

$\therefore u(x,t)=\int_0^\infty C_1(s)e^{-kts^2}\sin xs~ds+\int_0^\infty C_2(s^2)e^{-kts^2}\cos xs~ds$

$u(0,t)=\alpha(t)$ :

$\int_0^\infty C_2(s^2)e^{-kts^2}~ds=\alpha(t)$

$\int_0^\infty\dfrac{C_2(s^2)e^{-kts^2}}{2s}d(s^2)=\alpha(t)$

$\int_0^\infty\dfrac{C_2(s)e^{-kts}}{2\sqrt{s}}ds=\alpha(t)$

$\mathcal{L}_{s\to kt}\biggl\{\dfrac{C_2(s)}{2\sqrt{s}}\biggr\}=\alpha(t)$

$C_2(s)=2\sqrt{s}\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{kt\to s}\{\alpha(t)\}$

$\therefore u(x,t)=\int_0^\infty C_1(s)e^{-kts^2}\sin xs~ds+2\int_0^\infty s\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{kt\to s^2}\{\alpha(t)\}e^{-kts^2}\cos xs~ds$

$u(x,0)=0$ :

$\int_0^\infty C_1(s)\sin xs~ds+2\int_0^\infty s\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{kt\to s^2}\{\alpha(t)\}\cos xs~ds=0$

$\mathcal{F}_{s,s\to x}\{C_1(s)\}=-2\mathcal{F}_{c,s\to x}\{s\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{kt\to s^2}\{\alpha(t)\}\}$

$C_1(s)=-2\mathcal{F}^{-1}_{s,x\to s}\{\mathcal{F}_{c,s\to x}\{s\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{kt\to s^2}\{\alpha(t)\}\}\}$

$\therefore u(x,t)=2\int_0^\infty s\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{kt\to s^2}\{\alpha(t)\}e^{-kts^2}\cos xs~ds$

$-2\int_0^\infty\mathcal{F}^{-1}_{s,x\to s}\{\mathcal{F}_{c,s\to x}\{s\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{kt\to s^2}\{\alpha(t)\}\}\}e^{-kts^2}\sin xs~ds$