# closed form solution to the heat equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

Let smooth functions $f(x) , g(t)$ are given
solve the heat equation on the semi infinite domain $(a,\infty) \times (0,T)$.
for simplicity, we can let $a = 0$.
\begin{eqnarray}
&&u_t(x,t) = u_{xx}(x,t) \quad a<x<\infty , \quad 0<t<T \\
&&u(x,0) = f(x), \quad a<x\\
&&u(a,t) = g(t),  \quad 0<t<T \\
&& lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} u(x,t) = 0 .
\end{eqnarray}
i need the  closed form solution to the problem subject to $f(x) , g(t)$

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Here is a solution for $f(x)=0$  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350742/find-the-greens-function-and-solution-of-a-heat-equation-on-the-half-line/350758#350758  For the general case, though, you may need a Green function approach.

Comment: Thanks,
in my problem $f(x) \neq 0$ ,but $f$ has this property: $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 0.$

Answer (score 2):

For the last condition to be true one has to make some assumptions on $f$. Such as $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x) = 0$. For example, if $f\equiv1$ then $\lim_{x\to +\infty} u(x,t) = 1$. The solution can be expressed as a sum of two potentials: $G*f+2Wg$, where $G$ is the Green function of the first boundary value problem and $Wg$ is  double layer potential for the heat equation.

Comment: thanks for your help 
but I have difficulty to calculate $Wg$.  
From definition of double layer potential, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
W [g(x,t)] = \int_0^t \int_S 
 \frac{\partial}{\partial n_y } \Phi(x-y , t- \tau) g(y,\tau) dS_y d \tau  \quad\quad (1)
\end{eqnarray}
Here $$\Phi(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}^3 e^{-x^2/4t} $$
In my problem $g(x,t)$ is only a function of time $t$ and the boundary $S$ contains two pints$\{a,\infty\}.$ 
How to calculate the inner integral in (1)?

Comment: The boundary is one-dimensional. So $S$ is just a point and $Wg$ can be written as
$$
W g(x,t) = -\int_0^t 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \Phi(x-a , t- \tau) g(\tau)  d \tau, 
$$
$$
\Phi(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}} e^{-x^2/4t}.
$$

Comment: But a bout term $G*f$, I consider the Green function 
$G(x,t) = (\frac{1}{4 \pi t}) ^{3/2} e^{-\frac{(x-a)^2}{4 t}} $
The convolution product can be written as
\begin{eqnarray}
G(x,t) * f(x) &=& \int_0^x G(x-\lambda , t) f(\lambda) d\lambda  \\
&=&  (\frac{1}{4 \pi t}) ^{3/2} \int_0^x  e^{-\frac{(x-\lambda-a)^2}{4 t}}  f(\lambda) d\lambda
\end{eqnarray}
But this convolution does not satisfy the PDE. 
Do you mean that the convolution of $G(x,t)$ must be calculated with respect to $t$?
thanks for your guidance again.

Comment: As is written in the books on PDF (for $a=0$)
$$
G(x,t,y)=\Phi(x-y,t)-\Phi(x+y,t)
$$
and the integral in question is
$$
\int_0^\infty G(x,t,y)f(y)\,dy.
$$

Comment: In fact we splited the problem into two parts.

part $1$:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&u_t = u_{xx}\\
&&u(x,0) = f(x)\\
&&u(0,t) = 0\\
&&\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} u(x,0) = 0
\end{eqnarray}
with the solution $$u_1(x,t) = \int_a^{\infty} (e^{ \frac{(x-y)^2}{4t}} - e^{\frac{(x+y)^2}{4t}}) f(y) dy$$

and part $2$:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&u_t = u_{xx}\\
&&u(x,0) = 0\\
&&u(0,t) = g(t)\\
&&\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} u(x,0) = 0
\end{eqnarray}
the solution of part $2$ is  $$u_2(x,t) = \frac{x}  {2\sqrt{\pi}}  \int_0^t g(\lambda) (t-\lambda)^{-3/2} e^{-\frac{x^2}{4(t-\lambda)}} d\lambda.$$

$u = u_1 + u_2$.

Answer (score 0):

As a hint, I suspect you'll want to use Duhamel's principle where the solution to the problem with time-variant conditions is the convolution of the transient BC with the constant BC version of your problem...