# Evaluation of $\int_0^T \int_0^t \tau^{-1/2} (T-\tau)^{-1/2} \exp(\frac{ix^2}{2(T-\tau)})d\tau dt$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

This Integral is giving me headaches:
$$I(x|T):=\int_0^T \int_0^t \tau^{-1/2} (T-\tau)^{-1/2} \exp(\frac{ix^2}{2(T-\tau)})d\tau dt$$
where $x$ and $T$ are positive reals.

Can it be evaluated in terms of elementary functions?
Can it be evaluated in terms of special functions (Bessel, Gamma, Error, ...)?

Sadly, I can't provide starting points, because I have not found any promising ones.

**Edit 1:**

So, I've tried a couple things now.
First of all, taylor-expanding the Exponential function and switching summation and the integration is not possible in this case:
$$\int_0^T \int_0^t \tau^{-1/2} (T-\tau)^{-1/2} \exp(\frac{ix^2}{2(T-\tau)})d\tau dt \neq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{ix^2}{2})^n \frac{1}{n!} \int_0^T \int_0^t \tau^{-1/2} (T-\tau)^{-(n+1/2)}d\tau dt$$

Next, I simplified the Integral a bit, so that I'm now dealing only with:

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^t \tau^{-1/2} (1-\tau)^{-1/2} \exp(i\frac{b}{1-\tau})d\tau dt=\int_0^1t^{-1/2}(1-t)^{1/2}\exp(i\frac{b}{1-t})dt=:J$$
where $b$ is a positive real.

As pointed out in the comments, this being an convolution integral, it could be written as an inverse Laplace transformation:

$$J(b)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{\mathcal{L}[t^{-1/2}]\cdot\mathcal{L}[(t)^{1/2}\exp(i\frac{b}{t})]\}(1)$$

And while I can find sources on $\mathcal{L}[(t)^{1/2}\exp(\frac{b}{t})]$ (in the DLMF, for example), an expression for $\mathcal{L}[(t)^{1/2}\exp(i\frac{b}{t})]$ seems hard to come by. (Mathematica provides the following:$$-((1+i) (-1)^{7/8} \pi  \left| b\right| ^{3/4}
   \left(\text{ber}_{-\frac{3}{2}}\left(2 \sqrt{s} \sqrt{\left| b\right| }\right)-i
   \text{ber}_{\frac{3}{2}}\left(2 \sqrt{s} \sqrt{\left| b\right| }\right)+i
   \text{bei}_{-\frac{3}{2}}\left(2 \sqrt{s} \sqrt{\left| b\right|
   }\right)+\text{bei}_{\frac{3}{2}}\left(2 \sqrt{s} \sqrt{\left| b\right|
   }\right)\right))\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} s^{3/4}}$$
where bei and ber are some Kelvin functions I never heard of.)

Could it be possible to compute:
$$J'(b)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{\mathcal{L}[t^{-1/2}]\cdot\mathcal{L}[(t)^{1/2}\exp(\frac{b}{t})]\}(1)$$
and use analytic continuation to get $J(b)$?

Also, [A difficult one-variable exponential integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148493/a-difficult-one-variable-exponential-integral?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Find the Green's Function and solution of a heat equation on the half line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350742/find-the-greens-function-and-solution-of-a-heat-equation-on-the-half-line/350758#350758) seem relevant.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. For info about how we would like questitons to be posed, please see "How to ask a good question" at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question . That page has advice about providing context (what is the source of this integral? What is its motivation?) and also advice about how to write a good question when you don't know how to start. You can edit this post to improve it.

Comment: this might help:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1958258/a-closed-form-for-the-integral-int-01-frac1-sqrty31-y-exp-left-frac

Comment: To whoever bookmarked this: By now I have found a (lengthy) solution. If you want to see it let me know.