# inverse Laplace transform of $e^\sqrt{as}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform, residue-calculus

I am trying to find the inverse Laplace transform of $e^\sqrt{as}$ for $a>0$.
So we need to solve $\oint_B dz \: e^\sqrt{az} e^{z t}$ (Bromwich contour), but not sure how to start. How do we even see where the poles are?

Thank you

Comment: fyi, Mathematica says only sqrt[a]<0 `InverseLaplaceTransform[Exp[Sqrt[a s]], s, t]` is `ConditionalExpression[-(Sqrt[a]/(E^(a/(4*t))*(2*Sqrt[Pi]*t^(3/2)))),  Sqrt[a] < 0]`

Comment: See this solution, which illustrates that the problem is the branch point at $s=0$: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347933/compute-the-inverse-laplace-transform-of-e-sqrtz?rq=1

Comment: What I am not sure about is on $C_5$ where does the minus sign go in front of $i\sqrt x$.

Comment: @RonGordon Is that due to the branch cut?

Comment: @bart: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @RonGordon Okay, but I am still not seeing why is $e^{-\sqrt{x e^{-i \pi}}}=e^{i\sqrt{x}}$ on $C_5$

Comment: @bart: $\sqrt{e^{i \pi}} = e^{i \pi/2} = i$.  OTOH  $\sqrt{e^{-i \pi}} = e^{-i \pi/2} = -i$

Comment: @RonGordon Ah, thank you!

Comment: @bart I suppose that there is a typo in the wording : probably it isn't $\exp(\sqrt{as})$, but $\exp(-\sqrt{as})$
Then, find the Laplace transform of $\exp\dfrac{-a/(4x)}{x^{3/2}}$ and see what is obtained.: