# How to calculate inverse laplace of $e^{a\sqrt s}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative, laplace-transform

I was using Laplace to find solutions for $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$

with boundary conditions 
$$u(0,t)=1  \\
u(1,t)=1  \\
u(x,0)=1+ \sin \pi x$$

I used $U(x,s)= \mathcal L^{-1}{u(x,t)}$
and got $$U(x,s)=Ae^{x\sqrt s} + Be^{-x\sqrt s} + \frac{1}{s} + \frac{\sin \pi x}{s+\pi ^2}$$

$$u(x,t)= A\mathcal L ^{-1} \{e^{x\sqrt s} \} + B\mathcal L ^{-1} \{e^{-x\sqrt s} \} + 1 + e^{-\pi ^2t}\sin \pi x$$

How to solve for the first two inverse Laplace terms?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347933/compute-the-inverse-laplace-transform-of-e-sqrtz/348021#348021

Comment: $L^{-1}\{e^{\sqrt{x} s}\}$ or $L^{-1}\{e^{a \sqrt{s}}\}$ ? the former is easy but is a distribution, it is  $f(t) = \delta(t+\sqrt{x})$  (so you made a mistake elsewhere as your initial condition is not a distribution)

Comment: @user1952009 sorry about it - just corrected it