# asymptotics of inverse Laplace transform of $\exp(\sqrt{s^3}-\sqrt{(s+1)^3})$

Tags: asymptotics, laplace-transform

I haven't been able to find the inverse of the Laplace transform image $$F(s)=\exp\left(\sqrt{s^3}-\sqrt{(s+1)^3}\right)$$
in the tables or using Mathematica. Computing the contour integral around the branch cut seems difficult. Has anyone seen this one before or know a trick to attack it?

**ADDED**
Contour integration yields the following integral representation:
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}(F)(t)=$$
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\left(\int_0^1 \sin\left(s^{3/2}\right)\exp\left(-(1-s)^{3/2}-st\right)ds+\int_1^\infty\sin\left(s^{3/2}-(s-1)^{3/2}\right)\exp(-st)ds\right)$$
which agrees with the numerical [inverter](http://www.pe.tamu.edu/valko/public_html/Nil/) maintained by Peter Valkó. These integrals appear hopeless to compute explicitly, although I would be interested in getting an asymptotic as $t\searrow 0$. The asymptotic as $t\to\infty$ is $\frac{3}{4e\sqrt{\pi}}t^{-\frac{5}{2}}$ which follows from Watson's lemma applied to the first term. I'm not sure how to obtain the small $t$ asymptotic, though.

Comment: any reason to believe that there exists a nice closed form?

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/348021/301977) might give you some ideas

Comment: @tired All I know is that modulo a normalization factor, $F$ is the Laplace transform of a probability density that has a finite mean but infinite variance.